# making navigation items separate fading images

Tags: javascript, html, fade

I'm building a simple navigation menu with four links. The menu has a greyscaled  background image sliced into four parts that when hovered over will fade in a colored section of the background image, basically creating a saturation/desaturation effect on mouse over. The code im using works but only for one of the four slices. I need to figure out how to get each item to fade in separately. While messing with the code, ive been able to get either, one or all to fade in on hover, but can't figure out how to "break" them up.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$('div.menu').hover(function() {

var fade = $('.one', this);


if (fade.is(':animated')) {

  fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
} else {

  fade.fadeIn(250);
}
}, function () {

var fade = $('.one', this);

if (fade.is(':animated')) {
  fade.stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
} else {

  fade.fadeOut(500);
}
});
});
```

below are pics of whats happening
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUiwe.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn6RN.jpg

Comment: could u post ur code or a fiddle sample? so that someone can help u..

Answer (score 1):

Couldnt you do this using CSS? Here is a sample with transitions

```
.menu-item{
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .2s linear;
}
.menu-item:hover {
opacity:0;
}
```

Here is another with CSS animation

```
.menu-item:hover{
animation: fade;
-webkit-animation: fade;
}

@keyframes fade{
from{opacity:1;}
to {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade{
from{opacity:1;}
to {opacity:0;}
}
```

You can add delay parameters, timing, iteration count, etc.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp